# git cherry pick from remote master branch without other remote changes

Tags: git, cherry-pick

Let's say I am working on my `master` in my own repository. My upstream for example is `main-upstream`.

But I need one specific commit from another remote - `special-upstream`. I don't want another changes from it - I do not need all commits from that remote and I don't want any changes from it - it's a different project - except one certain commit with certain hash from branch `master`.

Is it possible to `cherry-pick` it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the other repo as a remote and fetch it's commits:

```
git remote add otherremote <url to other remote>
git fetch otherremote
```

Cherry pick the commit from the other repo

```
git cherry-pick <sha1 from otherremote>
```

This will cherry-pick the selected commit into the current branch.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. `git fetch` the remote, then `git checkout master ; git cherry-pick <commit>`. Same as usual. As long as you only `git fetch` and not `git pull` or `git checkout special-upstream/xyz`, you will not "pollute" your own repository with anything else.